# ASP.Net Prevent compare validator and regular expression validator from firing at the same time

Tags: asp.net, validation

I've got two text boxes like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTextBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1" ErrorMessage="Not a positive real number." Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="(^0*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?$)|(^0*\.0*[1-9]+\d*$)" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFldTextBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1" ErrorMessage="Enter a number." Display="Dynamic" />

<asp:TextBox ID="textBox2" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTextBox2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox2" ErrorMessage="Not a positive real number." Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="(^0*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?$)|(^0*\.0*[1-9]+\d*$)" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFldTextBox2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox2" ErrorMessage="Enter a number." Display="Dynamic" />
<asp:CompareValidator id="compareValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox2" ControlToCompare="textBox1" Type="Double" Display="Dynamic" Operator="LessThan" Text="Error." />
```

It's two text boxes that have regular expression validators that constrain them to only allow positive real numbers.  These work fine.

I also want the input in the second text box to be smaller than the first one.  For that I have a compare validator.

When the user has correct numbers the compare validator works fine.

It's when they enter in anything that fails the second regular expression validator, that the compare validator also fires at the same time.

It doesn't matter what's in the first text box, valid input, wrong input, or even nothing.  Both of the second validators fail.

Even though the validator is supposed to be comparing doubles.

Is there an easy fix for this?

I realize that this behavior is *okay*, because a validator is invalid when it should be, but the user would be seeing the incorrect error messages.

I've already done a solution involving custom validators and Javascript, and if it comes down to it then I'll have to do that again.  But if that's the case then there's not much point to using a compare validator, since it'll never work with a regular expression validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign different validation groups to regular expression validator and compare validator and use ASP.NET inbuilt javascript function `Page_ClientValidate()` to check validation one by one.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTextBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1" ErrorMessage="Not a positive real number." Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="(^0*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?$)|(^0*\.0*[1-9]+\d*$)" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFldTextBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1" ErrorMessage="Enter a number." Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Group2"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="textBox2" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTextBox2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox2" ErrorMessage="Not a positive real number." Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="(^0*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?$)|(^0*\.0*[1-9]+\d*$)" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFldTextBox2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox2" ErrorMessage="Enter a number." Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Group2" />
<asp:CompareValidator id="compareValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox2" ControlToCompare="textBox1" Type="Double" Display="Dynamic" Operator="LessThan" Text="Error." ValidationGroup="Group3" />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return Validate()" />
```

In Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Validate() {
            var isValid = false;
            isValid = Page_ClientValidate('Group1');
            if (isValid) {
                isValid = Page_ClientValidate('Group2');
            }
            if (isValid) {
                isValid = Page_ClientValidate('Group3');
            }
            return isValid;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Evaluating them in order worked well.  I modified your implementation a bit to have it be called dynamically as the text changes.  I added an onchange="Validate();" tag to the second text box and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Custom Validator for second textbox to confirm that Comparison logic occurs if regular expression validation passes. You could do it the following way-

```
<asp:Textbox id="textBox2" runat="server" text=""></asp:Textbox>
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate = "textBox2"
ErrorMessage = "Your Error Message"
ClientValidationFunction="validateLength" >
</asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateLength(oSrc, args){
 // your validation logic here
}
</script>
```