# How to prevent CompareValidator from firing while trying to fire RegularExpressionValidator in ASP.NET Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my small piece of aspx  code inside a GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="60px" DataField="Product_Quantity" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity")%>' />
<asp:Button ID ="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Quantity_Update_Click" ValidationGroup="UpdateQuantity" CommandArgument="Button12" CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Must be greater than 0" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Integer" ValueToCompare="0" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numbers only but no decimals" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>      
</ItemTemplate>
```

In TextBox1, if I type 0, then only the CompareValidator message fires and which is exactly what I want.

Again in TextBox1, if I type 2.5 **OR** if I type abcd, then both the CompareValidator message and RegularExpressionValidator message fires at the same. But in this case, I want only RegularExpressionValidator message to fire. I don't want CompareValidator message to fire.

So, how do I prevent both the CompareValidator message and RegularExpressionValidator message fire at the same ?

This is the only minor issue I need to get it fixed.

It would be helpful if the recommended fix or syntax solution is provided.

Comment: Use `CustomValidator` instead of the two.

Comment: @Alex Kudryashev ...This is what I have tried  - <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Must be greater than 0.09" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Currency" ValueToCompare="0.09" ErrorMessage="Numbers with only 2 digits after decimal" ValidationExpression="^\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}$"></asp:CustomValidator> ... But when I'm testing it, now it is not showing any validation error message at all

Comment: `customValidator` control doesn't have operator, type, and validationexpression properties. But it has `clientvalidationfunction`. Read docs.

Comment: @Alex Kudryashev ... If possible, it would be helpful if you could refer back to my .aspx code in my post and also my .aspx code in my comment and then post an answer with CustomValidator :)

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35569422

Answer (score 0):

Validation of a single row in a DataBound control (`GridView`) is tricky and multiple validation is even trickier. `CustomValidator` is a sharp tool which can combine any or all other ASP.NET validators. This is how you can use `CustomValidator` in `GridView`.

```
//.aspx
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID ="txtQty" runat="server" Width="60px" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity")%>' />
<asp:Button ID ="Button1" runat="server" 
    OnCommand="Quantity_Update_Command"
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("productid") %>' <%--some information. else it makes no sense --%>
    ValidationGroup='<%# "UpdateQuantity"+Container.DisplayIndex.ToString() %>' <%--validation group must be unique for each row --%>
    CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="valQty" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtQty" 
        ValidateEmptyText="true"
        ClientValidationFunction="qty_validate" <%--javascript on client --%>
        ValidationGroup='<%# "UpdateQuantity"+Container.DisplayIndex.ToString() %>' <%--validation group must be unique for each row --%>
        OnServerValidate="valQty_ServerValidate" <%--never trust user input or JS validation --%>
        >*</asp:CustomValidator>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Custom validation starts (if possible) on Client side.

```
<script>
    function qty_validate(sender, args) {
        if (parseInt(args.Value) != args.Value) {
            sender.innerHTML =
                sender.errormessage = 'Numbers only but no decimals';
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else if (parseInt(args.Value) <= 0) {
            sender.innerHTML =
                sender.errormessage = 'Must be greater than 0';
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

But it is not enough. Never trust user input and client side (JS) validation.

```
//.cs
protected void valQty_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    //repeat validation logic on the server
}
//extra: Call OnCommand handler instead of OnClick
//Here you can use e.CommandArgument unavailable in OnClick handler
protected void Quantity_Update_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //update product using e.CommandArgument
}
```